# Erase/reset DOM and global variables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, webview, electron

I'm writing an electron app, but it's a question about JavaScript/HTML5 in general. I want to load local content in a webview and then open iframes from particular remote resource inside it. Unfortunately I can't because of [X-FRAME options](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5036). So I came with a workaround. The idea is to load the remote content, erase the dom and inject my own local content using custom file protocol to embed local resources.

Basically I want to totally erase everything, no matter what is loaded into the webview. I got the erasing the dom part with document.write(). But how could I unset all variables that could have been set by that page? Or could I prevent the document from being written to in the first place? Or is there any better, less hacky way to do what I want to do? This is my current code which erases dom:

It runs from a preload script, before anything else:

```
(function() {

var originalProperties =  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window); //global variables, before dom is loaded

var injectDOM = function() {

    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', injectDOM);

    //trying to erase global variables set by remote resource, if any. Is there a better way?

    var newProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

    var difference = newProperties.filter(x => originalProperties.indexOf(x) == -1);

    for (i = 0; i < newVariables.length; i++) {

        if (window.hasOwnProperty(newVariables[i])) {
            window[newVariables[i]] = null;
            delete window[newVariables[i]]
            //some variables still stay, delete return false, however they are nulled
            //but is there a better way to do that and what about possible attached event listeners?
        }

    }

    var html = '';

    html += '<!-- automagically injected-->';
    html += '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    html += '<html>';
    html += '<head>';
    //html += '<script>alert("test");</script>';
    html += '</head>';
    html += '<body>';
    html += 'hello world';
    html += '</body>';
    html += '</html'>;

    document.write(html);

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', injectDOM);
```

I also tried comparing Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window) before and after the dom was loaded, but something tells me its not the best way to do it.

Update: I managed to solve the problem more elgantly with @wOxxOm's help. I posted my solution in the original github issue https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5036

Comment: Maybe it's possible to strip X-Frame headers using [webRequest.onHeadersReceived](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-request/#webrequestonheadersreceivedfilter-listener)?

Comment: I will try it, thanks. I have a little trouble understanding it. This:   mainWindow.webContents.session.webRequest is for main window and webview has different webcontents and I have to hook it to webview webcontents, right? If so, how could I access webview webcontents?

Comment: Use `partition` attribute for `webview` tag, then access its session with `session.fromPartition`?

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time, but I still can't get it to work. In the main process, I have win variable defined for the main window. When I do win.webContents.session.fromPartition() I get that .fromPartition is not a function. console.log(win.webContents.session) shows empty object in the terminal.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't know the session is an object of its own. Thank you again, you saved me hours. It seems to work! I have problems with protocols mismatch now, but I hope I will solve it in similar way.

Comment: When you get it working, could you do a self-answer? (Or possibly a new question with self-answer, if your approach is significantly different to what you originally asked.)

Comment: I posted my solution on the github issue relating the problem. If anyone has a similar problem, he will find that page on google. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5036